# How to implement standard functionalities using SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'd like to build suitescript implementing same functionalities with standard function.

For instance on item detail page (List/WebSite/Items) clicking view button of any non inventory item, you could find out Convert To Inventory button.

Thanks to inspect that browser support, it shows some as follows [image]

I want to build script that archive same functionalities like getNLMultiButtonByName('multibutton_convertinvt').onMainButtonClick(this);return false; but it throws error like getNLMultiButtonByName is not defined.

I want your help. 
Regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're looking for something similar

```
function onLoad(type, form, request){
     if(type=='view') {
            form.addButton('custpage_button','Custom Button',"getNLMultiButtonByName('multibutton_convertinvt').onMainButtonClick(this);return false;");
        }

}
```